# Layer over contact form and z-index (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: forms, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don´t know what´s overriding my contact form and i can´t put the mouse to write...

Here´s the [form](http://firenetworks.eu/abc3/#contacto)

Thanks so mucbh in advance!!

Comment: please provide more detail.

Comment: more detail of what???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given your containing div a class of "sobre", with a z-index of -1. Because of this, the row div is given precedence, basically "overlaying" your form. Remove this z-index and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `z-index: -1`:

```
.sobre {
    background-image: url("../img/sobre-elephant4.png");
    width:1180px;
    height:463px;
    /* z-index:-1; */
}
```

(Line 280 in style.css)

Comment: Thanks so much, didn´t know that i had a z-index: -1! :)